# Looks like British people say "They're at the cinema." Don't Americans say "They're at cinema"?

Tags: american-english, definite-article, british-english

I have seen a difference in the use of "the" between UK and US and that is in the word hospital, is it the same in the word cinema?

> I'm in the hospital (US)
> I'm in hospital (UK)

> They're at the cinema ??
> They're at cinema ??

From the British grammar book, it seems that "the" is always used for cinema. ( Essential Grammar in Use-British)

[image: British "Essential Grammar in Use"]

Comment: To be "at *the* cinema" is, as far as I know, said by both British and American English speakers.

Comment: Wouldn't Americans say "at the movie theater" anyway?

Comment: Americans would always say "at **the** cinema/movie theater/movies".   (And yes, Americans don't tend to say *cinema*.)  Your title doesn't seem to match your question, though.

Comment: In the UK we say "They're at **the** cinema". The definite article is not optional here.

Comment: You seem to be thinking that if the UK/US pattern is "in hospital," "in the hospital," then if UK speakers say "the X," then US speakers would say the reverse? This is not a generalizable pattern, see Astralbee's answer

Answer (score 3):

There is a definite American vs. British English thing going on, but not "at the" vs. "at", rather "movies" vs. "cinema". I checked Google Ngram Viewer. In British English "at the movies" is about 40% as common as "at the cinema". In American English it is 2 1/2 times as common.  But, for both places, the use of the article is much, much more common that without.

Answer (score 3):

No. British English speakers say "at the cinema", but most American English speakers say "at the *movies*".

You're confusing the difference between the way the two dialects refer to hospitals, which is just a peculiarity. It doesn't necessarily apply to all other kinds of places you might be 'at'.

British people say "*in hospital*" to mean *hospitalised*, ie admitted as an inpatient. But they might say a person was "in *the* hospital" to mean someone was in the hospital building for any other reason, for example if they work there or are visiting. Americans don't have this idiomatic way of referring to someone who is hospitalised - which is why they say "**in** *the* hospital".

Comment: *but most American English speakers say "at the movies"* That would strike me as odd/older way of saying it. I might say "he's seeing a movie," or "he's at the theater," but "at the movies" sounds like something my grandma would say.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- That's because 'cinema' is the name of the building, whereas most Americans would call the same building a 'movie theatre'. So, when they say 'the movies' they are referring to the experience of watching a movie rather than the building. The other peculiarity of that is that "**in** the movies" would refer to things that take place within the context of a movie (eg "*real life isn't like the movies!*"), whereas a British English speaker could say "**in** the cinema" to mean inside the building. They are two very different idiomatic ways of referring to the same activity.

Comment: I understand the connotations, I am a native AmE speaker. I was disputing that “at the movies” is what “most” speakers would say.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- You say 'cinema'?

Comment: No, I'm not sure why you would think that.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him-  I didn't. The cinema/movies issue is something of a red herring anyway, as my answer covers. The OP is thinking about the way BrEng speakers refer to hospitals.